# I don't succeed in hiding paragraphs using >!

Tags: support, markdown, formatting, spoilers

I found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/editing-help) in the *spoilers* paragraph that putting >! would hide the following 
things, which was a way for me to alleviate a question's heavy presentation by hiding 
paragraphs that could be seen if and only if details are needed, but using >! did not work... 
(See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194080/the-tensor-product-of-admissible-morphisms-of-semi-normed-modules-over-a-normed).) Where is my error, and is it indeed possible to do this with >!, or with an 
other sythax?

> As Emil Jerabek has already written in a comment, hiding a paragraph actually works if you put the >! at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Consider the failure a feature. Excepting actual spoilers, hiding text in this way is very annoying, not to mention that it is next to impossible to access the hidden text at all on mobile devices.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't agree with you completely one this one. It is quite handy in some situations to hide things in this way. Exemple : #pragma regions or scopes in visual studio, even if depending on version it is not always hovering but clicking. Anyway ;-) But, whatever our opinions may be on this, it is supposed to be a feature (as I seen the the link I mention, so it should be either remove from this features link, or addressed (in the case it's not just me not knowing how to use it.)

Comment: The syntax is basically correct, but: (1) you need to have the >! at the beginning of a line, just like for regular blockquotes, and (2) apparently, you can’t use displayed equations `$$...$$` inside the spoiler block.

Comment: Ok, so it's me misusing it, but it's indeed useless for my purpose - but very good to know nevertheless. Thx !

Comment: I agree with @EmilJeřábek And, it starts to be even more annoying when some others use "empty" blockquotes for formatting.

Comment: @quid: What do you mean "empty" blockquotes?

Comment: @Asaf a block-quote that contains nothing normally visible like `>${}{}{}{}{}{}$` It just creates a gray bar that some seem to like as design-element.

Comment: Another reason to avoid spoiler markup is that it is [inaccessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301971).